# dpkg fatal error when installing linux-headers

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg, linux-headers

In simple terms, the problem that I have is that I am trying to install the linux-headers for my kernel and I get the error

```
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.4.0-97.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package `pptp-linux' contains empty filename
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

The rest of the post explains what happened and how did I reach to this state. Before that the linux headers were working properly.

---

I was working on a remote server when my connection was dropped. I was using a software library that depends on the linux header files which I installed with `$sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-97-generic` a few weeks ago.

After I gained access I rebooted the system and then I couldn't connect remotely. I went to the server room and the server's monitor was displaying an error, saying that the `/boot/` partition doesn't have enough space. So realized that there were many different versions of the `linux-heaaders-*` installed into the system and I tried to run: `$ sudo apt-get remove` but I always had a problem with the dpkg with an error similar to one displayed below.

I couldn't do anything so, manually with `rm -rf` I deleted the `abi`, `config`, `initrd`, and `vmlinuz` files for all the version other than the one I use and the previous one. Afterwards, I run `sudo apt-get autoremove` and then `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo update-grub`.

After that I tried to re-run the software I was running before the connection was dropped and the software wouldn't run (actually is a software and a driver at the same time). I tried to re-`make` and I got an error saying that the linux headers do not have a `build` sub-directory.

Then I tried to reinstall the linux headers for my kernel's version.

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-97-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-97
The following NEW packages will be installed
  linux-headers-4.4.0-97 linux-headers-4.4.0-97-generic
0 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 0 to remove and 18 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/10.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 87.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.4.0-97.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package `pptp-linux' contains empty filename
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I also run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-4.4.0-97-generic
```

and (to remove the previous versions of the header files):

```
$ sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-4.4.0-80-generic
```

but I get a similar error message. And `$ sudo apt-get update` doesn't help. Also, I have to run `$ sudo dpkg --configure -a` from time to time.